# Call a function to get the Sent Date when an e-mail is sent and that works with all types of connected e-mail - Outlook - VSTO

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I did two different implementations to solve my problem, which is:
I need that when an email is sent, it calls a function that with it I can get The **Sent Date**.
Both implementations work, not 100% but they work.

```
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {

        //First implementation.
        try
        {
            Outlook.Stores stores = Application.Session.Stores;
            foreach (Outlook.Store store in stores)
            {
                var folder = store.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
                items = folder.Items;
                items.ItemAdd += ItemsAdd;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Log.Error(exception.Message);
            throw;
        }

        //Second implementation.
        this.Application.ItemSend += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend);
    }
```

First implementation: With it I can return the correct **Sent Date**, however it is not working with all types of emails that are being used in the Outlook App, for example, I have my microsoft email that works with it, and a business email that was connected as POP3 and with this account does not work.

Second implementation: It works with all types of e-mails but gets the wrong Sent Date.

Is there a solution in the first implementation to work with accounts connected as POP3? or another implementation that solves my problem?

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: The first implementation may not be working when you are not working with the default folder.  The POP account may not be the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are subscribing to the same folder when you iterate over all stores in the profile:

```
            foreach (Outlook.Store store in stores)
            {
                var folder = store.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
                items = folder.Items;
                items.ItemAdd += ItemsAdd;
            }
```

Instead, you need to use the `store` object to subscribe to a store-specific `Sent Items` folder.

```
foreach (Outlook.Store store in stores)
            {
                var folder = store.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
                items = folder.Items;
                items.ItemAdd += ItemsAdd;
            }
```

Also it makes sense to keep a list of `Items` objects because each time the code overwrites the object reference, so previous objects could be released by the GC at some point of time.

The [Store.GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.getdefaultfolder) method returns a `Folder` object that represents the default folder in the store and that is of the type specified by the `FolderType` argument. This method is similar to the `GetDefaultFolder` method of the `NameSpace` object. The difference is that this method gets the default folder on the delivery store that is associated with the account, whereas `NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder` returns the default folder on the default store for the current profile.

The `Application.ItemSend` event is fired before the item is sent out, moreover the process can be cancelled by others. So, you can't be sure the item is sent at that stage.

Comment: Thank you for the help, now my project is work correctly!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, as Eugene noted, you keep retrieving the same default Sent Items folder  - use `store.GetDefaultFolder` instead.

Secondly, you keep resetting the same variable (`items`).

If you want `ItemAdd` event from Sent Items folder on each store, you need to create a wrapper class that retrieves the Items collection from the store passed as a parameter to the constructor and set up an event handler as a method on the wrapper class. You can then store a list of wrappers in a list to ensure they are alive and can raise events. Something along the lines

```cs
List<StoreWrapper> _stores = new List<StoreWrapper>(); //global level
...
foreach (Outlook.Store store in stores)
{
    _stores.Add(new StoreWrapper(store));
}
...
public class StoreWrapper
{
   private Items _items;
   public StoreWrapper(Store store)
   {
      _items = store.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail).Items;
      _items.ItemAdd += ItemsAdd;
   }
   private void ItemsAdd(object item)
   {
      //todo
   }
}
```